# What is wrong with this C program

Tags: c

I am trying to write a usb mass storage driver. I don't have a storage device, so I am trying to allocate some memory. below is the program I wrote to emulate
a 512*2048 (1 MB) size usb drive

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


char ** called_func(char **mem, char start_sec, char num_of_sec)
{
    char **read_mem, row, column;
    read_mem = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * 512 * num_of_sec);
    for(row = 0 ; row < num_of_sec ; row++)
       for(column = 0 ; column < 512 ; column++ )
            read_mem[row][column] = mem[row + start_sec][column];

    return read_mem;
}

int main()
{
    char **mem, row , column, i, j;
    char **ret;
    mem = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * 512 * 2048);

    if(mem == NULL)
       printf("allocation failed\n");
    for(row = 0; row < 2048 ; row++)
       for(column = 0 ; column < 512 ; column++)
           mem[row][column] = 'a';


    ret = called_func(mem, 2, 6);//start sec, num of sectors this time I am going to read from the second sector, and total 6 sectors
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<6;j++)
      {
        printf("ret[i][j] = %c",i, j, ret[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;


}
```

I haven't wrote a C program in many months. Please tell where I am wrong as I keep getting segmentation fault.

Comment: Paste the error you are getting including error line and relate it to your code above.

Comment: Try debugging. Use your favourite debugger, and the errors will come to life. :D

Comment: A simple segmentation fault.

Comment: @Angelo. Screenshots are not a good way to post errors. Please post a copy of the error as properly formatted text for us to see.

Comment: That's not how this site works. Read [ask].

Comment: Ok, don't worry I will find the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that you are not allocating memory for each `char*`. `mem` is a pointer to a pointer. This means this value will need allocation (as you do):

```
mem = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 2048);
```

You can remove the `512` from your code because this only needs memory for the pointers themselves not the actual characters in the pointers.

Then you need to `malloc` each individual `char*`. You could do this inside your `for` loop:

```
mem[row] = malloc(513);
```

This allocates memory for each `char` pointer. Keep in mind you need to add space for the `null` character at the end.

To `free` these you are going to need a loop similar to this:

```
for(row = 0; row < 2048; row++)
{
    mem[row];
}
free(mem);
```

That will get rid of the individual pointers and the double pointer.

This is enough to get you started but there are a few other issues with your code. I would recommend either using some type of debugger or simply adding print statements to watch what is happening with the code as it runs.

Comment: Is the code wrong?? I definitely need to revise,

Comment: There are parts that are wrong. One example is you are using `row`, `column`, `i` and `j` as if they were `int` but you called them as `char**`. Another would be never adding the null character at the end of your char pointers. This can cause a lot of issues when trying to read them.

Comment: Thats very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a basic mistake that is very common if you forget pointer concept.

mem was a pointer to pointer.

1.So first it needs to know what memory size it is going to point.Hence

```
mem = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * 2048);
```

2.Then it contains the pointers. Those pointers need to know what memory size they are going to point so,

```
 for(row = 0; row < 2048 ; row++)
        mem[row]=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 512);
```

3. Once the pointers knows their limits, we can simply fill all of the pointed memory

```
      for(row=0 ; row < 2048 ; row++)//points to char *
         for(column = 0 ; column < 4 ; column++)//points to char
            mem[row][column] = 'a';//any data
```